# Assembly/gdb: add behavior

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, addition

While running an ELF program with GDB, I am currently witnessing a rather unexpected behavior for a specific add instruction:

Intel syntax:  `add    cl,BYTE PTR [eax]`

AT&T syntax: `add    (%eax),%cl`

I expect this instruction to have the same meaning as gdb's `set $cl=$cl+*((char*) $eax)` (regardless of the triggered flags). But the behavior is not the same for a certain debugging session (see below): the value of (char) *$eax is 0xb8 and the value of $cl is 0, but the resulting value of $cl is 0xcc.

My question is: where does this 0xcc comes from? Why is the result not 0xb8?

The program is just another crackme program which may be found [here](https://www.cymric.net/ch20.bin).

To answer Jester's comment below, the following gdb session works as expected though:

```
(gdb) b *0x08048119
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048119
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/ch20.bin
Welcome to Root-Me Challenges
Pass: foo

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048119 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $eip
=> 0x8048119:   add    (%eax),%cl
(gdb) x/bx $eax
0x8048080:      0xb8
(gdb) p/x $cl
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) si
0x0804811b in ?? ()
(gdb) p/x $cl
$2 = 0xb8
```

But I don't understand why the following one does not give the same result:

```
(gdb) b *0x8048080
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048080
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/baz1/Downloads/ch20.bin 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048080 in ?? ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048085 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x0804808a in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x0804808f in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x08048094 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
Welcome to Root-Me Challenges
Pass: 0x08048096 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x0804809b in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x0804809d in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x080480a2 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x080480a7 in ?? ()
(gdb) 

0x080480a9 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x080480ab in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x080480b0 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x080480b5 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x08048115 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x08048117 in ?? ()
(gdb) 
0x08048119 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $eip
=> 0x8048119:   add    (%eax),%cl
(gdb) x/bx $eax
0x8048080:  0xb8
(gdb) p/x $cl
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) si
0x0804811b in ?? ()
(gdb) p/x $cl
$2 = 0xcc
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Post complete transcript of gdb session. Check that you only stepped a single instruction. Also make sure the value in memory does not change (e.g. due to multi-thread program, or accessing invalid memory).

Comment: The site seems to be down or the link is broken. As for the gdb log I was hoping to see proof of your claims (registers and memory before-after and the instruction itself). Being a crackme it may very well be doing something tricky :)

Comment: I uploaded the file on my vps and changed the link ; it should work now.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the instruction at `0x08048119`. For me, afterwards `cl` is `0xb8` as expected.

Comment: Yes I am.
Should I conclude a faulty processor / version of gdb / whatever ?

Comment: More likely user error :D  Post your version of [this](http://paste.debian.net/367584/).

Comment: You're right, this does work. However, why does the procedure I follow in the updated description produce the 0xcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `b *0x8048080` places a software breakpoint into memory which happens to be the `int3` instruction with opcode `0xcc`. The `add` instruction will then read this instead of the original memory content. You can delete the breakpoint after it got hit or use hardware breakpoints that don't modify the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jester!
I guess programs do not read their code often enough to justify an additional check to prevent this kind of problem.
I still find it weird though that gdb does the check when evaluating *$eax for instance then; it creates some kind of inconsistency between what we see and what actually happens from the instructions' point of view...